# problems about intellij IEDA

Tags: android, intellij-idea

When I use the Intellij IDEA to create android project, I find that there are only `drawable-ldpi`, `drawable-mdpi` and `drawable-hdpi` in the diretory `res`. So how could I do to generate `drawable-xhdpi` and `drawable-xxhdpi` in `res`? In eclipse there is no such a problem.

Answer (score 1):

do it yourself.

right-click on res. choose new android resource directory. change type to drawable and name dir accordingly.

Comment: you are right! I can add these dirs manully now. Can the IDE generate them automatically?